# Calculation of border-image-width with border-image-outset

Tags: html, css

***Background:***

[Here](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#border-image-width) is how W3C spec defines `border-image-width`.
[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-width) is how MDN explains `border-image-width`.

[Here](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#border-image-outset) is how W3C spec defines `border-image-outset`.
[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-outset) is how MDN explains `border-image-outset`.

We all know how border-image-width works. It takes border box and computes it value based on that. But how does it compute it's value when we use it along with border-image-outset as border-image-outset property changes the border image area to extend beyond element box area. Please look at figure below: (Image taken from [here](https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/border-image-outset/))

[image]

***Claim:***

The following example shows us that border-image-width still gets computed on height and width of external edges of border box.(Which does not make sense but anyways)

Border image used:

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Border-image-width</title>
    <style>

        p.ShowingBorderImageOutsetExample1{
            border: 3px solid black;
            width:500px;
            border-image-source: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlCZO.png");
            border-image-slice: 20%;
            border-image-width: 1;
            border-image-outset: 6px;
            outline: 1px solid black;
        }

        p.ShowingBorderImageOutsetExample2{
            border: 1px solid black;
            width:500px;
            border-image-source: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlCZO.png");
            border-image-slice: 20%;
            border-image-width: 1;
            border-image-outset: 6px;
            outline: 1px solid black;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="ShowingBorderImageOutsetExample1">Hi this is just a demo</p>
<p class="ShowingBorderImageOutsetExample2">Hi this is just a demo</p>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see that we have kept border-image-outset and border-image-width as constant.Only thing changes is border-width due to which change occurs. This hints that border-image-width was computed on boder-width.

***Question:***

Now, though it seems little weird as to why border-image-width still gets computed on border box , my question is how does it then adjust those corner image pieces , those top width image pieces etc on the extended new dimensions ?

Please note that border-image-slice gives us pieces and those pieces were stretched (by default) on the dimensions given by border-image-width. But due to usage of border-image-outset, dimensions have changed. No body holds those dimensions. Border-image-width still clings to dimensions given by border box.

Comment: Since the `border-image` properties is somewhat complex to explain, I'm not sure if to post an answer. This article might shed some light, so let me know if it makes things more clear: https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/border-image-width/

Comment: @LGSon Article says nothing in context to border-image-outset. It just explains the normal working of it as explained in MDN too.

Comment: I will post an answer tomorrow (11.50PM here now) ... you have a few statements in your question that is inaccurate and when we have sort those out, I'm sure you will understand how it works

Comment: As Harry posted a good answer for you, pretty much saying what I was about too, I will not post one of my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The computation of `border-image-width` does not actually depend on `border-image-outset`. Outset just ***specifies an offset*** at which the border image should be drawn and has no impact on the width of the border.

As mentioned in the specs, when you use a pure number value (without percentage sign or any units) for the `border-image-width` property, the computed width value is a multiple of the `border-width`.

> **<number>**
>   Numbers represent ***multiples of the corresponding computed border-width.***

<sup>(emphasis in the description is mine)</sup>

So, for your case, the `border-image-width` is 1*3px (= 3px) for the first example and is 1*1px (= 1px) for the second example. This is what you see from the output also. The border image is ***thicker in the first example*** than that in the second one.

The `border-image-outset` just tells the UA that the `border-image` should be painted at an offset of X pixels from the original border-box of the element. The ***offset is outside*** the element's original border-box because it is an outset border. In your case, it is offset `6px` to the top, bottom, left and right of the original border-box of the element. Because of this, for the first example we see a 3px wide border and a 3px wide gap (as outset is by 6px in total) whereas for the second example we see 1px wide border and a 5px wide gap (again as the outset is 6px in total).

---

**Summary of discussion in comments:**

As you rightly point out, once an outset is added the dimensions of the outer rectangle (one created by the outset) will be bigger than that of the inner rectangle (the original `border-box` of the element) but that does not result in any increase in dimensions of `border-image-width`. The `border-image-width` just defines the ***thickness*** of the border-image (actually that wording difference can also be a cause of misunderstanding at times) and the thickness remains the same irrespective of whether the border is drawn around the inner rectangle (the original `border-box`) or the outer rectangle (the offset box).

What actually happens is that the image that is used for the border (`border-image-source`) is sliced in to pieces based on the `border-image-slice` property and then the individual pieces are first placed at the 4 corners based on the `border-image-width`. Then, the remaining portion that is in the center will be filled up based on the `border-image-repeat` setting (round/space/repeat). The no. of pieces in the middle will be more than normal because the offset outer rectangle is wider at the top and bottom while it is taller on the right and left.

This can be understood by having a look at the [first example that is available under the `border-image` section in the specs](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#border-images):

> [image]

Comment: Let's say border-image-width is 3px as in 1st example. this means image painted on top width will have 3px width and length = (length of outside border to edge - 6px). Now, we also have defined outset. Hence, the new place where the top edge image piece has to be painted will have length > (length of outside border to edge - 6px). Did you get where I am pointing ? But the border-image-width holds that dimension value as = (length of outside border to edge - 6px).

Comment: Nope, I am not getting you at all. The outset is a fixed position. It is defined by the value that you give for that property and then from that point on in the border-image is painted inwards depending on the width of the image itself. If the image's width is equal to the offset it fills the entire space upto the outside edge of the original border-box. If image's width is smaller, it will leave a gap between the painted image and the outside of the original border-box.

Comment: okay let's break it down. Do you agree that border-image-width is always calculated on border-width irrespective of border-image-outset is mentioned or not ?

Comment: Yes, `border-image-width` is independent of the `border-image-outset`.

Comment: Cool. Now, forget outset for a minute. Let us just visualize border-width and border-image-width. We know that image border will be applied from outer border edge towards inside. That image border dimensions are completely based on border-width + border-image-width. Let us say , the image at top edge was 200px X 3px. Now suddenly I apply border-image-outset = say 6px. Whole image border now begins from 6px above. For this border-image needs to be enlarged as now it begins from an 'illusionary outer border' which is at 6px away from 'real outer border'. Dimension of img border increased?

Comment: Sorry from where did you get this `border-width` + `border-image-width`? Did you mean math or just that it is dependent on those two? And note that the ***dimension*** never increases, only the ***position*** changes due to the offset. `border-image` will not be enlarged based on the `border-image-outset`, it just gets painted starting from the position indicated by the outset. Think of it as similar to the positioning attributes. The `left` or `top` doesn't affect the height or width of an element. It just says where the element is placed.

Comment: If I draw a rectangle inside a rectangle , the outer rectangle have larger dimensions. Think of now image border. How would you just move it from inner rectangle to outer rectangle without increasing it's dimensions ?

Comment: No no. I am not saying addition. Just dependent on those 2 properties.

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin: Sorry, I don't know how to explain this to you. See the width of the top/bottom part of the border-image will increase and the height of the left/right parts will increase because as you've put it the outer rectangle is bigger than the inner (original border-box) and these are handled by the `border-image-slice`, `border-image-repeat` properties to see how they fill the whole area. But neither the height of the top/bottom parts nor the width of the left/right parts increase and so there is no need for the outset to have an impact on the image width.

Comment: I'd recommend you to have a look at the example right at the start of [the border-image section in the specs](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#border-images). You'd see how the `border-image-outset`, `border-width` and `border-image-width` properties interact. As you'd note from there the `border-image-width` doesn't change, just the middle part gets repeated (round/stretch/repeat) after placing the images of the given size at the 4 corners. Thus there is no need for the dimensions of the image to actually change.

Comment: Ok. I get it now. Border-image-width only helps to calculate width. It never decides the length.

Comment: Thanks @Harry for your patience.